# Chrome keyboard handling inconsistent in full screen mode / progressive web apps

Tags: javascript, android, fullscreen, android-softkeyboard, progressive-web-apps

[image: Fullscreen mode]

There is an **inconsistency in how the onscreen keyboard in Android affects the browser** (Chrome 59, Aug 2017):

1. *On the left:* you see a blue page with a yellow footer with a text input element
2. *In the middle:* The input element was selected and the keyboard shows. The browser moves the footer to the top
3. *On the right:* the browser runs in fullscreen mode and the kayboard now does not properly move the footer but instead overlays it.

The footer uses:

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
```

**We want to have the middle experience in a full screen scenario** (in a progressive web app, where the same problem exists).

How is this possible?

**The Demo**

I've put together a codepen demonstrating the problem. Visit this URL in your phone: https://codepen.io/EnlightningMan/full/jLxOEq/ (sorry, no short links allowed)

Or view the code for the codepen here: https://codepen.io/EnlightningMan/pen/jLxOEq

Comment: Have you found the answer to this problem? I'm currently facing the exact same problem!

Comment: This problem seems to be fixed in up-to-date chrome, but stays in other browsers!